# Get actual Revision Number of Repository In TFS

Tags: tfs

Im using the tf.exe and I need to know the actual Revision ID on my Team foundation server.

I tried *tf history*, but I simply need the latest revision.

I am using TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2008.

An Environment Variable would do it for me.

Comment: What's the kind of source control type do you use?  TFVC or Git? And what's your real requirements? Do you mean that you want to get the latest `Revision number` of Git repository or just get the latest version (changeset for TFVC or commit for Git) of the files?

Comment: I am using TFVC and I simply need the latest revision number. I want to display it in the version details.

Comment: Whats' the version of TFS do you use? Based on my understanding, you want to get the latest changeset right? What's that mean for `display in version details`? the  `version details` is a tab or a page...? Sorry still can not get you very well. Could you please clarify your question, capture screenshot if possible.

Comment: When I make a new build of my application I would like to indicate the current changeset ID (Revision Number). So it should look like this: Major.Minor.Revision (e.g 1.0.1892). I want to automate this by using the tf.exe. I dont want to get the latest files, just the revision number.

Comment: Btw thank you for helping

Comment: @MirkoG Please update your question with the TFS version: it is a big constraint

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the tf.exe, if you are using vNext build (TFS 2015 and later version), you can directly use the predefined variable `Build.SourceVersion` to get the latest version value (changeset ID) in current build. See [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#predefined-variables) for details.

Then you can set the **build number format** with the variable `Build.SourceVersion`:

e.g : `$(TeamProject)_$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Build.SourceVersion)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`

But note that the variable `$(Build.SourceVersion)` in **build number format** is only available when builds were triggered automatically on commit/checkin (on Continuous integration). It can not be resolved when you queue build **manually** and keep the `Source Version` field as **empty** (by default it will get the latest version). **So, if you queue build manually, then you need to specify the specific `Source Version`** (e.g `C458`) in the queue build dialog. See my reply in another thread : [Using SourceVersion and rev:r in TFS2015 build names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177081/using-sourceversion-and-revr-in-tfs2015-build-names/48180550#48180550)

Another workaround is getting the latest changeset with the variable `Build.SourceVersion` first and then upgrade the build number automatically within the build process.

Comment: I am using TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2008. I need to maintain old applications. How can I make this variable visible in my .rc file? I would like to define this variable in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2010 means XAML builds, so you need to use the `IBuildDetail.SourceGetVersion` property.
The simplest way is to assign a variable just before the `UpdateBuildNumber` activity; the variable value is computed mixing the build number computed by TFS and the above property.

Comment: Can I access this during Pre-build Event?

Comment: My suggestion requires editing the Build Template. It should be possible to use a pre-build script but tougher

Comment: Not really, I think I will use tf changeset /latest /noprompt and parse its output.

Comment: @MirkoG Suggest you migrating to vNext build, TFS 2010 and VS 2008 is too old. See [Why You Should Switch to Build VNext](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/why-you-should-switch-to-build-vnext) for details. Then you can follw below answer to achieve that.